# Freebase autosuggest to exclude types

Tags: autosuggest, freebase

is it possible to exclude certain types from the freebase autosuggest?

This is my general code,

```
$("#myInput")
 .suggest({"key":API_KEY})
 .on("fb-select", function(e, data) {//blah blah});
```

is possible to do something like (which doesnt work)

```
 $("#myInput")
 .suggest({"key":API_KEY,"filter":"(any type:-/business)"})
 .on("fb-select", function(e, data) {//blah blah});
```

or

```
 $("#myInput")
 .suggest({"key":API_KEY,"filter":"(exclude type:/business)"})
 .on("fb-select", function(e, data) {//blah blah});
```

if anyone has any ideas :D thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(not type:/business)`.  I haven't tried it for an entire domain, but that's the syntax for a type.